# Need help with recalcitrant shower faucet handles

Tags: shower, faucet

I have a leaking shower faucet (two-handle shower-only) as seen below.  The faucet handles won't come off and I'm wondering if they are non-standard in some way.  I've used (1) a handle puller (2) wiggling them with vice grips (3) WD-40 soak.  They don't seem to budge and I'm afraid of forcing them more.  Any advice?  (Needless to say, I removed the screw).
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to spray wd 40 behind the taps.  Tap is probably on a spline shaft and struck.  When using wd 40 also give taps some easy hits with hammer to give some vibration.  Puller should then remove them.

Comment: With the screw out, _liberally_ soak with WD-40 and let it soak in for a while. I've also found that _PB Blaster_ is even more effective at loosening stubborn bolts, though that's usually on the car where rust & road grime are an issue. You may need to use something like CLR to break up any scale. It may take multiple liberal doses of multiple chemicals to break up years of build up.

Comment: Along with WD-40 (which fixes everything) You might also try some CLR (lime remover)

Comment: With the iron stains I would try CLR possibly first. I have not mixed it with a penetrating oil I would read up on the precautions.

Comment: Wd40 is what you use when you don't have the right stuff.  Use a penetrating oil or other "stuck bolt remover" fluid designed to reduce rusted interior bits.